# grunt for SAPUI5

Tags: gruntjs, sapui5

I am configuring grunt for SAPUI5 project. I can configure grunt taks for minify, test and etc. I see there is grunt-ui5 grunt plugin but I am not able to understand what exactly this plugin is doing or useful to SAPUI5 projects.

Thanks

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 2):

The grunt-openui5 plugin by SAP is documented at [github](https://github.com/SAP/grunt-openui5/blob/master/README.md).

It can be used to build UI5 themes and package components and libraries into preload-files.

UI5 tries to load most of the modules of a component or library with a single request from a component-preload.json / library-preload.json file. If it cannot find a preload file, it has to request all modules individually resulting in many many requests and thus poor performance.

grunt-openui5 is used to create these preload files. It also minifies the code while doing so.

The grunt-ui5 plugin is something inofficial which seems to do similar things. You would have to ask the author directly to get more information. I recommend to use the official grunt-openui5 plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For ui5 applications it's not common to use the grunt task for minification , instead we use the grunt-openui5 task. It will create the preload file, which  is a json object that contains the whole app.

```
{
"version":"0.0",
"name":"app name",
"modules":[ 
    "control1": "code for control1",
    "control2": "code for control1",
    ]}
```

When control1 is required, ui5 just uses the preload to get the code for control1. In this way, ui5 avoids triggering a new request. Anyway, If the preload file is not present, it will have to request control1.js . 
If you want to see a real preload file, open any ui5 app and go to the network tab of the browser.

Using the grunt-openui5 plugin for grunt, it will do the work for you, and will give you as a result a library.css, rtl,  library-parameters.json (same thing, but for themes) and the preload.json (for the js files).

Instead of using grunt-ui5, I would recommend you to use the the oficial plugin [grunt-openui5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-openui5)!

Answer (score 0):

[grunt-openui5](https://github.com/SAP/grunt-openui5) is a really amazing grunt plugin created by bunch of SAPUI5 core dev team ;)

It mainly allow you to do 4 things:

- create Component-preload.js (optimized and minified version of your app)
- create library-preload.js (optimized and minified version of a custom library)
- create a custom theme
- create a local web server to test your app locally

I've covered it a little bit on my blog post [Custom Control 101](https://medium.com/@stermi/custom-control-101-sapui5-openui5-tipoftheday-customcontrol-fd51a85bbed3) if you want to check it out.

I'm using it in daily basis and you can read some of [my blog posts](https://medium.com/@stermi/) about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small remark: in the future, consider switching from grunt to gulp, as gulp is newer and faster. For SAPUI5 there are packages with same functionality in gulp, as ingrunt.